# How to name columns in custom content provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-cursor

how should I call columns in a Cursor which I'm returning from custom ContentProvider to allow other apps to read data from it.

I have all columns declared in ProviderContract, but 3rd apps dont know that.
Is this documented?

What I want to do in particular is to let the user to share data (file - images and pdfs) from my app to other apps..
Because of security, all data is encrypted on external sd storage. So I need to proxy them through my app to decrypt them. 
Android security system should handle the issue of only letting other apps read from the content provider after the user choose to share the file. Thats ok, but I have problems that other apps dont know how to read the data from my cursor.

I just feel that Android will have some mechanism to do that:) Either by standardized column names, or by some adapter mechanism.

this is code of my query method..

```
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    MatrixCursor c = new MatrixCursor(SecuredFileContract.Files.PROJECTION_ALL);
    String name = uri.getLastPathSegment();
    File file = new File(name);
    byte[] fileContents = mStorageProxy.getFileContents(file);
    c.addRow(new Object[]{1, uri.getLastPathSegment(), fileContents, 0});
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a standard for letting the 3rd party app know how to get them from my Contract class..

That's called "a Web page", or some other form of documentation.

For example, the reason you know the column names for the SDK-supplied providers is because that's (somewhat) documented in the JavaDocs.

You need to document:

- the `Uri` pattern(s) that you are expecting, particularly for key `Uri` values (e.g., `CONTENT_URI` values for queries)
- the column names that can be requested in a projection
- the "rules of the game" for how you are interpreting the `selection`, `selectionArgs`, and `sortOrder` parameters to `query` (e.g., can these be considered ordinary SQL using your column names?)
- etc.

Whether you supply this documentation in the form of Web pages, a PDF file, a training video, or something else, is up to you.

---

**UPDATE** based upon edit:

> What I want to do in particular is to let the user to share data (file - images and pdfs) from my app to other apps

Then you need a `ContentProvider` that supports `openFile()` or `openAssetFile()`. Ideally, it also supports `query()`, but specifically for [the `OpenableColumns` projection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/OpenableColumns.html), not arbitrary stuff.

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/Pipe) demonstrates what your `ContentProvider` would need to do, though you would need to replace my read-the-file-from-assets logic with your read-the-encrypted-file-and-decrypt-it logic.

Comment: How I could missed the openFile() method..Anyway, one last question:) openFile returns ParcelFileDescriptor which I think is not suitable for me because I don't have a decrypted version of the file on the disk at any time.
I've just found out MediaStore.MediaColumns http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns.html
Isn't it exactly what I need? I need to send an array of bytes rather than a ParcelFileDescriptor.

Comment: @simekadam: "openFile returns ParcelFileDescriptor which I think is not suitable for me because I don't have a decrypted version of the file on the disk at any time" -- you can create a pipe `ParcelFileDescriptor`. This is shown in [the sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/Pipe). "Isn't it exactly what I need?" -- you are not implementing `MediaStore`. "I need to send an array of bytes rather than a ParcelFileDescriptor" -- please click on the link to [the sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/Pipe).

Comment: if only there was a support for API level 8..I guess guys with prehistoric phones won't be sharing files..I won't give up on such elegant solution..

Comment: @simekadam: Yeah, sorry, `createPipe()` starts at API Level 9. Your only support prior to that would be to decrypt the file to a file (perhaps on internal storage) and use `open()` on `ParcelFileDescriptor`. This is not as secure, particularly since securely erasing flash doesn't work the way it does for magnetic media. OTOH, it also gives you a more compatible stream, as one downside of `createPipe()` is that the stream is not seekable, whereas a stream backed by a file is.

Comment: Yep, I guess we can live with that..2.2 userbase is way under 1% (for this particular app). I only need to write the logic to hide unsupported features there. Not a huge problem though..
What I like on the pipe is that it is non-blocking (if I implement is as you did), I just return one tail of it and the other app can immediately start reading data from it. 
I also spotted a lot of added methods with API level 19, I bet this is because of the new DocumentProvider, which is using ParcelFileDescriptors as its backing technology. (at least its devs say so, I didn't checked sources)